# pxe boot as an alternate boot for troubleshooting?

Tags: pxe-boot

My next question on pxe again, my pxe boot setup is fine and I am to build servers without any problem
Sorry if it’s a very basic question.

I wanted to boot my active server to network boot again as an alternate boot environment for troubleshooting (not to install any OS but wants to land in # )

Comment: Is it matter of boot device priority in BIOS?

Comment: and your question is... what?